# Lower bound for stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose the non-negative stochastic process $(X_t,Y_t)$ is such that $E\{X_t - X_a | Y_u \in A \,\,\forall u \in [a,t] \} \geq Z(A)(t-a)$. Let $T_{A}$ be the time of a visit to $A$. Assuming that the equilibrium distribution exists, can we conclude that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} E[X_t | Y_t \in A] \geq Z(A) E[T_A]/2$ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Could you tell us what are your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: We stay in $A$ for an expected amount of time $T_A$. When $Y_t$ is in $A$, $X_t$ grows at least with linear rate $Z(A)$ for a time $T_A$. The average value for $X_t$ when $Y_t \in A$ is then at least $Z(A) E[T_A] / 2$ I think.

Further, we have $E[X_{T_A}] \geq Z(A) E[T_A]$ (because $X_t - Z(A) t$ is a submartingale and $T_A$ a stopping time). The average value in $[0,T_A]$ is then $Z(A) E[T_A]/2$ I think.

Comment: what is a submartingale? What is Z?

Comment: $Z$ is just a constant, as defined my original post. For more information about martingales see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_%28probability_theory%29 (I am not sure if it is useful here)

Comment: "Let T_A be the time of a visit to A" You might want to add a precise definition of T_A since some heavy assumptions might actually be hidden behing the existence of this T_A.